# Get data from Access database present on a different server

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need to connect to an access database file from my web application. The access database file is present on a different server. Is there any way of connecting to the access database file? Is it possible? I tried searching but could not found something to start with. I can connect to something present in the server where my web application is located. I need an approach.

Comment: You can, so long as the database file is in a location shared on the network that can be reached from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a file share to the remote server.  You can pass a full UNC name in the access connection string, sucn as:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source="\\server\share\Filename.accdb";Mode=Share Deny None
```

You will need to have the appropriate NTFS and Share permissions on the file. (Read/write)

Comment: Thank You. Instead of Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0, I had to use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. But rest worked fine.